# Getting metadata in EF Core: table and column mappings

Tags: entity-framework-core

Looking to get metadata in EF Core, to work with the mappings of objects & properties to database tables & columns.

These mappings are defined in the DBContext.cs OnModelCreating() method, mapping tables with .ToTable(), and columns via .Property.HasColumnName().

But I don't see this metadata under the Entity Types returned by...

```
IEnumerable<IEntityType> entityTypes = [dbContext].Model.GetEntityTypes();
```

Is this metadata available anywhere in EF Core?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> Is this metadata available anywhere in EF Core?

Yes it is. Just additionally to the properties examine the methods (`GetXXX`, `FindXXX` etc.). And pay special attention to `Relational()` extension methods.

For instance:

```cs
foreach (var entityType in dbContext.Model.GetEntityTypes())
{
    var tableName = entityType.Relational().TableName;
    foreach (var propertyType in entityType.GetProperties())
    {
        var columnName = propertyType.Relational().ColumnName;
    }
}
```

You need to have *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational* Nuget package installed.

**Update (EF Core 3.0+):** `Relational()` [provider extensions have been removed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#provider) and properties have been replaced with direct `Get` / `Set` extension methods, so the code for column/table names now is simply

```cs
var tableName = entityType.GetTableName();
// ..
var columnName = propertyType.GetColumnName();
```

**Update (EF Core 5.0+):** Since now EF Core supports separate column name mappings for table, view, sql etc., you have to pass the desired [`StoreObjectIdentifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.storeobjectidentifier?view=efcore-6.0) to [`GetColumnName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertyextensions.getcolumnname?view=efcore-6.0) method, e.g.

```cs
var tableName = entityType.GetTableName();
var tableIdentifier = StoreObjectIdentifier.Table(tableName, entityType.GetSchema());
// ...
var tableColumnName = propertyType.GetColumnName(tableIdentifier);
```

Comment: can we have any reference about this ?

Comment: @Sampath I can't find EF Core class documentation anywhere. All I have is the VS Intellisense.

Comment: Hmm..me too tried to find that.no success.anyway `+ 1` for your find :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Sometimes finding your way around EF Core is like looking for a property in a haystack ;-)

Comment: For any future arrivals to this question maybe this will help; I was able to find this documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ientitytype?view=efcore-6.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypeextensions.gettablename?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-relationalentitytypeextensions-gettablename(microsoft-entityframeworkcore-metadata-ireadonlyentitytype)