# How do I get the TableName from MetaData for .NET 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am having an issue where I'm trying to get the TableName to a variable. I am currently trying upgrade from version .NET Core 2.2 to .NET 6 and I'm getting this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IEntityType' does not contain a definition for 'Relational' and no accessible extension method 'Relational' accepting a first argument of type 'IEntityType' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The code in question is this.

```
TableName = entry.Metadata.Relational().TableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error describes, that method `Relational()` doesn't exist anymore for `EntityEntry.MetaData` instead I recommend using the `GetTableName()` method.

The below code should solve your problem.

```
TableName = entry.Metadata.GetTableName();
```

This question has also been answered here in more detail.
[Getting metadata in EF Core: table and column mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685271/getting-metadata-in-ef-core-table-and-column-mappings)